# How to configure spring boot for receive traffic only NGINX

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

For secure reasons I need my backend receive traffic only through Nginx. Is it possible to block outside all traffic to spring boot. And only NGINX can accept and send requests to Spring Boot application. Thanks for advice. Sorry for asking question in wrong so without code.

Comment: It is the best way that you might block outside IP addresses instead of the nginx traffic on the operating system's firewall.

Comment: thanks. ( tesekkurler abi deneyecegim :) )